# Installed APC php extesion on server but cant find a file to edit settings - apc.ini

Tags: php, apc, whm

I've installed the APC extension on a Dedicated server - admin using WHM ,the extension is enabled but I can find a file to edit the basic settings - if I try and add anything other than extension=apc.so to the php.ini file the site crashes..?

I've ran ~find . -name apc.ini but does not find a file..

Any ideas thanks

Comment: You may not have an apc.ini, some linux package managers do set one up. If you don't settings can be put right into php.ini.

Comment: I've tried adding direct to php.ini but as i said in my question it doesn't like it....? thanks

Comment: @datasage - sorry for late reply - error Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@shushushops.co.uk and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: 500 server error could mean just about anything. Can you turn on display_errors, or find out what error is occuring in the log files?

Comment: @datasage can't seem to find any errors - where would i find the log that may include this error ..? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was a configuration error when adding apc settings to the php.ini file I was not including  apc.enabled=1